# Apache setup: directive requires additional arguments

Tags: apache2

I am trying to use an Apache (only localhost). When I do `apachectl configtest` I get the following response:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 238 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
<Directory> directive requires additional arguments
```

The corresponding part of the httpd.conf file is

```
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
<Directory />
 Options Indexes SymLinks
 MultiviewsMatch Any
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I consulted several forums / the Apache documentation but I cannot see the mistake. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the idea of using `~` in http.conf?. Assuming you meant a user home directory: apache `http.conf` is not a bash script so expanding will not happen. You need either absolute paths or a relative path to the apache root.

Comment: Oh good to know! Thanks for pointing this out, I am quite new to this. I inserted the absolute path now but that did not solve the problem :( Any further advice?

Comment: I wasted hours on a silly confusion of line 238 with 283 – both are about directory. And then, there was a `/` missing... Thanks again and have a nice day

Comment: This answer appears to be no longer relevant to the (edited) question